# How do I calculate the position of a piston in percentage from the significant bits?

Tags: aviation-electronics

I have a ARINC label with 12 bits. This label is connected to a solenoid valve that is commanded to open partially or completely. If I get a feedback for bits set to 1 (significant bits). How do I calculate the position of the valve in percentage?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: ARINC data formats can vary, even endian-ness, as I understand it, what does the valve manufacturer's data say?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the resolution you want. 10 bits will give you a range of 1,024 to 1(000H - 7FFH), or a rounded off scale of 00.0 to 99.9%. 7 bits gives you a range of 127 to 1(00H - 7FH), or round it off to 00 to 99%. Add +1 so the final max reading should be 100%.

Please note this does NOT represent the actual torque or position of the solenoid as it is very non-linear with position. To convert the voltage or current of the solenoid to a torque value you will need to use a calibrated torque gauge to create a look-up table (LUT).

The first step is to make sure that a fully ON solenoid reads as 100% by coercing the maximum possible reading to be no greater than 100, then see how it scales downward to zero as the solenoid drive is reduced. If the scale makes sense you will not need to create a complex LUT.

An option would be to install a linear potentiometer, but they can be expensive compared to a software solution.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, this is very simple. Let's say that 000H (that's 000 in hexadecimal, and represents 12 bits) represents completely shut, and FFFH represents completely open. Furthermore, let's assume that the sensor is perfectly linear (that is, the output varies smoothly and linearly from closed to open). Then, since the full open is 4095 and full closed is 0, any position value x will form a fraction x/4095, and percentage will be 100 (x/4095), or x/40.95.

That is in principle. It is up to you to verify that all of the assumptions above hold. Is the shut value 000H? Is the open value FFFH? Is the output linear? There is no way to tell without either consulting the data sheet for the valve, or making measurements on your own. And just as a SWAG (Scientific Wild-Ass Guess) none of the above are, in fact, true. It will be up to you to compensate.